# Using g.Raphael in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, graph, sencha-touch-2, graphael

I checked out g.Raphael for creating simple charts. I managed to display them on a demo website, but I don't know how I can integrate them into my Sencha Touch 2 app now. I managed integrating it by using an iframe but this is not dynamic and performance lacks a bit too.

Can somebody please help or show me a tutorial?? Need help quickly.
Thanks!

---

Sorry had some code formatting issues ^^
Can you please point me into a direction? Do I have to put this into my view or a controller? I've included the Raphael files in my index.html for the ST2 app.

Heres my View:

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.Configurator', {
  extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
  xtype: 'configurator',
  requires: [
    'Demo.store.SampleStore'
  ],
  config: {
    title: 'Konfigurator',
    iconCls: 'home',
    direction: 'horizontal',
    directionLock: true,
    //Will be applied to every object in the array by default
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        cls: 'configurator-item',
        scrollable: true,
    },
    items: [
      {}
    ]
}
}
)
```

Thanks

Comment: @rixo
Guys I need some help here please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeees, I finally found it here - works perfectly:

[Link](http://vadimpopa.com/nvd3-and-raphael-as-alternative-charting-libs-for-sencha-touch/)

Answer (score 0):

What's preventing you from using both in the same page? Just include the Raphael's files, and you can use it to draw in Ext components.

For example:

```
var win = Ext.widget('window', {width: 600, height: 600, autoShow: true}),
    r = Raphael(win.body.id);

r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2]);
```